# What's wrong with this tinyscrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/J74VS/4/

I can't get it to work properly, I'm just trying to create a basic fiddle of a [tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/).

Comment: Where is the rest of the CSS ? There's a CSS file associated with the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing css. I mistakenly thought all you need is `$("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar()` to activate it.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J74VS/5/).